# Player is expelled from trigger when becoming child of a GameObject with a trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers, parent-child

The version used here is Unity 2021.3.25f1.

When changing the parent of my player when entering a trigger, my player "jump" and is "expelled" from the trigger.

The trigger on the right or left of the walkie stacker, before entering the trigger and parenting the player is normal, on the ground

[image: Image of the player and the walkie stacker, you can see the two box colliders on either side. Thoses are triggers]

After the parenting is done, the player is flying

[image: Same image as before but the player is flying]

Better view of all triggers, player isn't in the trigger anymore even without prior movement

[image: Image of the top view of the previous image, you can see that no colliders or triggers are touching]

The function used when parenting:

```
public void AttachPlayerToSelf()
{
    Debug.Log("position before attach : " + FirstPersonMovement.S.transform.position);
    FirstPersonMovement.S.rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
    joueurPCGO.GetComponent<FirstPersonMovement>().enabled = false;
    joueurPCGO.transform.SetParent(transform);
    Debug.Log("position after attach : " + FirstPersonMovement.S.transform.position);
}
```

In this code the "joueurPCGO" is the GameObject containing the player.

The algorithm when calling the function:

```
if (gerbeur.isPlayerOnSide)
{
                        if (!isPlayerAttachedToSelf)
                        {
                            AttachPlayerToSelf();
                            isPlayerAttachedToSelf = true;
                        }
}
```

Gerbeur is the walkie stacker GameObject.

The trigger enter function:

```
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    isPlayerOnSide = true;
}
```

I tried to limit gravity effects by making the rigidbody of the player kinematic with my script:

Image of the rigibody inspector at start

[image: Image of the rigidbody inspector]

But nothing changed.

Also tried to tighten the collider but nothing changed:

[image: Image of the player and his capsule collider tighter than the first one]

Also tried to not set rigidbody to kinematic when parenting but nothing changed.

Comment: looks like setting your player to non-kinematic is making physics push it out of the blue object. Make your player's collider smaller so it's tight with the mesh

Comment: There are no triggers shown here - so, collider pushed into collider will explode apart

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer I will try it, the collider of the player is a capsule as non trigger but the 3 colliders for the walkie stacker are set as triggers, I thought one of them as a trigger was enough for the collision to not explode :/

Comment: I changed the parent who's receiving the player and it's not exploding anymore but I don't really understand why. The new parent also has two trigger.